# 7.1 migration and Progress Indicator

Tags: java, progress-bar, vaadin

I'm moving to 7.1 from 7.0.5 version and I begin to change ProgressIndicator class with ProgressBar to refactor with the new polling mechanism.

This is returned error:

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.getState(Z)Lcom/vaadin/shared/AbstractFieldState;
    at com.vaadin.ui.ProgressBar.getState(ProgressBar.java:108)
    at com.vaadin.ui.ProgressBar.getState(ProgressBar.java:33)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.isReadOnly(AbstractComponent.java:535)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.isReadOnly(AbstractField.java:201)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:457)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:438)
    at com.vaadin.ui.ProgressBar.setValue(ProgressBar.java:93)
    at com.vaadin.ui.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:50)
    at com.vaadin.ui.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:40)

Anybody can explain me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have just upgraded from 7.0.5 to 7.1 and all I had to do in order to use the new, preferred `ProgressBar` was to change this:

```
ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
pi.setPollingInterval(1000);
```

to this :

```
Progressbar pb = new ProgressBar();
UI.getCurrent().setPollInterval(1000);
```

The second line should be called after the long running operation has been stared, because it causes the UI to poll for changes every second.

If you have a custom theme and don't extend any of Vaadin included themes, also don't forget to update styles for the new ProgressBar. HTML markup is the same, however, the default CSS class name is changed from `v-progressindicator` to `v-progressbar`;

Comment: I solved executing error, but progressbar is not showed! This is my code: private final ProgressBar progrBar = new ProgressBar(); -- Init -- progrBar.setImmediate(true); progrBar.setIndeterminate(false); progBar.setEnabled(false); --Use -- progrBar.setEnabled(true); progrBar.setValue(0f);